# TypeError: anchor.BN is not a constructor from script

Tags: anchor

Disclaimer: I am not very familiar with typescript, trying to learn while using anchor

I got the error from running a .mjs script as `node --experimental-modules --experimental-json-modules scripts.mjs`. BN is needed to trigger a call to a back-end rust function. On the other hand, anchor.BN can be successfully constructed in a test scripts I used.

Some code snippet

```
import * as anchor from "@project-serum/anchor";
const price = new anchor.BN(1e6);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `default` when using Anchor with ES6 modules (`import` etc) to work around this issue, eg:

```
import * as anchor from "@project-serum/anchor";
const { BN } = anchor.default; 
const price = new BN(1e6);
```